# How to pass textbox values to MVC Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tried the below but I get the compliation error:

> The name 'txtMakeModelTypeCode' does not exist in the current context.

```html
<label>Type Code</label>
<input type="text" id="txtMakeModelTypeCode" name="txtMakeModelTypeCode" />
<label>Make</label>
<input type="text" id="txtMake" name="txtMake"/>
<label>Model</label>
<input type="text" id="txtModel" name="txtModel"/>
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateMakeModel", "Vehicle", new { MakeModelTypeCode = txtMakeModelTypeCode, make = txtMake, model = txtModel })">Create</a>
```

I have also tried using a form but I don't want to use a submit button. Is it possible to use a plain button?

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateMakeModel", "Vehicle"))
{
  <label>Type Code</label>
  @Html.TextBox("txtMakeModelTypeCode")
  <label>Make</label>
  @Html.TextBox("txtMake")
  <label>Model</label>
  @Html.TextBox("txtModel")
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Comment: You are creating MVC application but not using the Model here. You need to go back to the basics of MVC and understand how to use model to display data in the view and collect data from the view.

Comment: If you want it to appear like a link (as in the first code snippet), then style it as a link (don't confuse appearance and behavior)

Comment: When does the error occur.What are the action parameters?If you access it using FormCollection You should be able to get all values in form collection.

Comment: Yes its possible to use button. 
On click event you can write 
$("CreateMakeModel") .submit(); method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC does not work the same as ASP.Net Webforms. The textboxes you create are not available in code. You use the controls to render your html and handling of data is done via the model.

So use TextBoxFor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateMakeModel", "Vehicle"))
{
    <label>Type Code</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MakeModelTypeCode)
    <label>Make</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Make)
    <label>Model</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Then in your controller, after the post, you should have the posted data in the model:

```
public ActionResult Index(CreateMakeModel model) // or is it Vehicle?
{
    // whatever you do here:
    string code = model.MakeModelTypeCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. This makes sense to me now. I was confusing myself with WebForms.